# Wireless not connecting automatically

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, login

My wireless is working fine, but when I login, it does not connect automatically, I have to select it from the list each and every time to use it.  Even though the `connect automatically` option is selected in the network options.

So basically, after booting it, I don't get connected to the network until I choose `connect to hidden wireless network`, followed by selecting the hidden network, and clicking connect.

Comment: Is the "available to all users" selected ?

Comment: @NikTh, That option is selected.

Comment: You can try to remove-delete the connection and create it from the begin.Open the network manager with **gksudo nm-connection-editor**

Comment: Just done that, and I am getting the same result.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Comment: bugs dont say they was come :)

Comment: It's not a problem with my 64bit install, but it is a problem on my 32bit install (non-pae).

Comment: I had similar problem with my laptop running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Same with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in 18.04 on a thinkpad t440s

Answer (score 0):

The password is probably not saved in system settings.

To fix this:

- Enter into "System settings -> Network"
- Select Wireless in the left pane and click the Options button
- Click the Wireless Security Tab.
- Enter the password in the password field and click the Save button

Comment: I made sure the password was saved a long time ago, so this is not the problem.  It doesn't want to automatically log me into hidden networks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my laptop running Ubuntu 12.10.

First thing first, make sure:

> > Connect Automatically and
> >     Available for all users are clicked in network settings.

And now, a small trick might work here. Once logged in and connected to wireless, just switch off the wireless physically (from the button) and start it again.
From the next start/reboot (or may be couple of reboots), it will start auto connecting.

Now don't ask me why.

Comment: Done this a few times now, and it's still not remembering.